# How to bind events in Jquery for an element created after document load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, bind

I have a set of list items in unordered lists that I bind the anchors inside them to fire when clicked. The thing is: Some ul's are created (via ajax) when I click on some of the li's created in the first place, binded in the jQuery's document.ready. And I want this li's that are created dynamically to fire as well. Can I do that?

Well, I hope you get what i mean...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check out [live() method](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Use it the same way as bind(), ie :

```
$('.class').live('click', function() { 
     alert('bla');
   }
);
```

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Answer (score 2):

The live() event will work on all ul elements even if you create them after you bind the live method to them. Like so:

```
$('ul').live('click', function() {
  // your code here...
}
```

See the info on live [here](http://api.jquery.com/live/).